# Combine multi-select question and list answers

Tags: c#

I would like to combine in a new multi-select question, answers of a first multi-select question with answers in a list

LINQ code in Survey solutions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I don't follow -- You aren't specifying what exactly you want. LINQ code in "Survey Solutions", "multi-select question"? I don't believe you can do that, sir :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately combining answers from two questions is not possible with current functionality.